# Object reference is required?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

am learning C# and have written a simple bit of code, but i don't understand why i have to declare the variables userChoice and numberR within the scope of the Main method and not within the scope of the class. If i declare it within the class like this, i get build errors

```
using System;

namespace FirstProgram
{
class Program
{
   string userChoice;
   int numbeR;

 static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a number...");
        userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        numbeR = Convert.ToInt32(userChoice);
        Console.WriteLine("You wrote {0}", numbeR);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

But only this will give me no errors:

```
using System;

namespace FirstProgram
{
class Program
{    
 static void Main()
    {
        string userChoice;
        int numbeR; 

        Console.WriteLine("Write a number...");
        userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        numbeR = Convert.ToInt32(userChoice);
        Console.WriteLine("You wrote {0}", numbeR);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Shouldn't i be able to use those two variables within Main just by declaring them in the Class like above? I am confused... thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it because `Main()` is a static function.  Your variables are declared as instance variables and can only be accessed on an instance of the `Program` class.  If you declare `userChoice` and `numbeR` as static variables, it will compile.

```
static string userChoice;
static int numbeR;

static void Main()
{
    //your code
}
```

Static members mean you can use the member without instantiating the class.  Imagine:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public static int StaticInt;
     public int NonStaticInt;
}
```

means you could do:

```
MyClass.StaticInt = 12;  // legal
MyClass.NonStaticInt = 12; // error, can't staticly access instance member
```

and all classes would have access to that change, since there is only one `MyClass.StaticInt` in your program. To change `NonStaticInt`, you would have to create an instance of that class, like so:

```
MyClass mine = new MyClass();
mine.NonStaticInt = 12;  // legal
mine.StaticInt = 12; // Error, cannot access static member on instance class.
```

Comment: Thanks very detailed answer with elaboration, helped me understand deeper.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your variables static since your Main method is static.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Main` is *static*, your variables would also need to be static in order to be used like this.  If you declare them as:

```
static string userChoice;
static int numbeR;
```

Then it will work.

You currently have them declared inside an *instance* of a `Program` object.  However, static methods (such as `Main`) are part of the type, not a specific instance.

Answer (score 1):

because `Main` is `static`

if you declare the variables (a.k.a. fields) as static too you can declare them in the class

static string userChoice;
   static int numbeR;

Non `static` methods and variables are called *instance* methods and variables. Instance variables relates to a specific object while `static` variables are shared among all created objects within the class.

The rules are that `static` methods can only call static methods and access `static` variables, but instance methods can call both `static` and non static variables and methods.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Main() is a static method and the two class fields (userChoice and numbeR) are instance fields.

Main() can be called statically, but the two class fields won't be defined until an instance of the Program class is created.

Answer (score 1):

The Main() method is declared as [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx). However, in your first code sample you declare two variables (userChoice & number) as instance variables. The static Main() method does not belong to a specific object, but to a certain type. Your variables however do belong to a specific instance of the Program type. You cannot use instance variables in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Main is static. You will have to declare the variables userChoice and numbeR as static. Then it will compile. Here is the corrected example:

```
using System;

namespace FirstProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static string userChoice;
        static int numbeR;

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write a number...");
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

            numbeR = Convert.ToInt32(userChoice);
            Console.WriteLine("You wrote {0}", numbeR);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```